# md-maxlength along with ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js 1.x (angular material)

```
<div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50">
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" name="qty" ng-model="SportEquipments.qty" md-maxlength="20" maxlength="20" required/>
    <div ng-messages="nSportEquipmentForm.qty.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">Quantity is required. </div>
        <div ng-message="pattern">Only Numbers are Allowed.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
</div>
```

I have put the `pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"` , when I save the data , its fine. when I populate the data, it red the field. and As I type and change the value, then validation done.. When I removed `md-maxlength="20"` , the behavior is normal

Comment: Try using ng-maxlength instead of md-maxlength

Comment: I think, after populating, your data length is > 20. So it is showing red. Check is this a case ??

Comment: @KaustubhKhare nope , lenght = 3 only

Comment: Could you make demo using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)?

Comment: ng-maxlength resolve the issue