# Input number with 2 decimal places and max length of 12

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have an input of type number, the value in this input will be saved in a column of type number(12,2), so I want to set the max length to 12 (12 digits in total,
2 of which are after the decimal point).

I tried as following :

```
<input type="number" md-maxlength="12" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$/" step="0.01" ..>
```

Whenver I type something it's invalid, this only occurs when I add the `md-maxlength="12"` which I use to display the max length under the input field.

[image]

As you can see in the picture the input is invalid.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

`ng-maxlength` instead of `md-maxlength` resolves this issue but the x/12 label under the input which indicates the max length is not displayed anymore.

## Edit 2:

The regex now indicates that only 10 number are allowed before decimal point (comma or dot) and 2 are optional after, you can see that the regex is working just fine here : https://regex101.com/r/fdDLFP/3, the problem is when I add the `md-maxlength`.

Comment: I think it is because you are using ``,`` in between. You can try entering number without ``,``.

Comment: @SandipNirmal ln french the comma annotation is used instead of dot, I don't think that's the problem since AngularJS supports i18n, so using the dot annotation results in the same problem.

Comment: Such questions are kinda stunning for me - you can open dev.console and see what does your pattern with /.../.test('...'). And this is pure JS, why you put angular/angular-material tags...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov the pattern is working fine, the problem is when I add `md-maxlength="12"` the input gets red and becomes invalid, there is a similar problem in stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409726/md-maxlength-along-with-ng-pattern but the provided solution was to use `ng-maxlength` instead of `md-maxlength`, by doing this, the little label under the input which indicates the max length will disappear, so I guess this is related to the angular-material.

Comment: @SandipNirmal I have modified the regex for more precision.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov please check my edit, the regex is not the problem, it's due to the angularjs material `md-maxlength` when combined with `ng-pattern`